# Error while installing second instance of Sitecore 10.3

Tags: installation, sitecore-install-framework

I already have one instance of `Sitecore 10.3` and when I am trying to install another one I'm facing the following issue:

```
Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Source'. The " Test-Path $_ -Type Leaf " validation script for the argument with value ".\createcert.json" did not return a result of True. Determine why the validation script failed, and then try the command again.
```

Can we only have *one* Sitecore instance in a machine? Do I have to remove the old one to have a new instance?

Comment: Welcome to SSE, Manjunath. It is possible to have multiple instances of Sitecore in a machine. Can you elaborate on your setup more ? How are you trying to set it up...

Comment: Have you tried all of the following? 1) Checked that `.\createcert.json` exists where expected. 2) You are running the commands as an Administrator. 3) Your script execution policy is permissive enough.

Comment: I am installing it using SIF. Yes I have the .\createcert.json in place and I am installing using admin previlages.

Comment: Please see this questoin and see if it helps: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/27787/validation-script-for-the-argument-with-value-createcert-json-did-not-retur/36707#36707